# Ejecutar PHP desde linea de comandos en segundo plano

Tags: php

Estoy usando las tareas programadas de windows para ejecutar un archivo PHP cada X tiempo, la cosa es que al ejecutarse se pone la pantalla del programa y pues quiero que sea en segundo plano...
La primera tarea que hice fue esta:

```
C:\xampp\php\php.exe -f c:/xampp/htdocs/tarea.php
```

Lo siguiente que quise probar fue ejecutar el CMD en el directorio htdocs y así usar *> NUL 2>&1* para que se ejecute en segundo plano, la cosa es que no supe cómo hacer para que cuando se abra el cmd con el programador de tarea se mande *PHP tarea.php* automáticamente... Agradezco cualquier ayuda ya sea para el primero caso, el segundo o alguna otra forma.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ya lo he solucionado, es muy sencillo. En la tarea programada, en la pestaña General aparece una parte llamada *"Opciones de seguridad"* con el usuario que está ejecutando la tarea. Se debe dar clic al botón *"Cambiar usuario o grupo"*, en el cuadro de texto escribir *"SYSTEM"* darle a aceptar y listo. Espero que le sea útil a quien tenga la misma duda que yo pues me la pasé casi toda la tarde buscando una forma de solucionarlo. :)